# Simple constraint (concept) gives g++ internal error

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

Following is an simple example that doesn't compile due to an g++ internal error (g++-7.0.1-20170412):

```
template<typename F>
concept bool FCallable() {
    return requires(F) {
        F::f();
    };
}
class Test1 {
public:
    template<FCallable P, FCallable... Pp>
    static void g() {
        P::f();
    }
};
class Test {
public:
    template<FCallable... P>
    static void g() {
        (P::f(), ...);
    }
};
class A {
public:
    static void f() {}
};
int main() {
    Test::template g<A>(); // gives an internal g++ error
    Test1::template g<A>(); // gives the same error
}
```

Is this a real error? That is: am I using illegal code or is this a bug in g++?
BTW: if I omit the constraint FCAllable and use typename... here, all goes well.

Comment: Internal errors are bugs.

Comment: I would say that the fact that variable name is same as function name is the origin of the bug.

Comment: No, I edited the example above. The error remains.

Comment: What is 'concept'?

Comment: Its a definition of C++ concept (since g++-6.3 with -fconcepts)

Comment: I'm not sure if the compiler's just pretty-printing it, but the `requires (FCallable<P>)()...` in the error message is not valid C++. That would need a fold expression over && or something, and I can't repro the ICE when I change the code to match the error, so *shrug*.

Comment: This seems to be [GCC PR 68372](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68372).